# Disallow robots can be bypassed with htaccess?

Tags: php, .htaccess, bots, robots.txt

I have a simple question. Let's say that I have this in **robots.txt:**

```
User-agent: *
Disallow: /
```

And something like this in **.htaccess:**

```
RewriteRule ^somepage/.*$ index.php?section=ubberpage&parameter=$0
```

And of course in **index.php** something like:

```
$imbaVar = $_GET['section']
// Some splits some whatever to get a specific page

include("pages/theImbaPage.html") // Or php or whatever
```

Will the robots be able to see what's in that html included by the script (`site.com/somepage`)? I mean... the URL points to an inaccessible place... (the `/somepage` is disallowed) but still it is redirected to a valid place (`index.php`).

Comment: The one with the question mark "?" -> The robots should be able to see what's in that html included by the script (site.com/somepage)?

Comment: now it looks more like a question.

Comment: `robots.txt` is kind of a guidance to the robots of what not to follow. Major ones will comply. However, it doesn't mean that they will all follow it, or for that matter that they will be forbidden to access the disallowed part. If you disallow a section of your site or entire site they will be able to see it, but they won't by your desire and their choice.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Assuming the robots will respect the `robots.txt`, then it wouldn't be able to see any page in the site at all (you stated you used `Disallow: /`.

If the robots however do not respect your `robots.txt` file, then they would be able to see the content, as the redirection is made server side.

Comment: Is there any way to test it? My guess is that they respect it but still I need 2 b sure. P.S. Yeah... it does look more like a question now.

Comment: @zozo: Google, Yahoo, and other NORMAL robots respect it

Answer (score 1):

No. By disallowing robot access, robots aren't allowed to browse any pages on your site and they're following your rules